# What is the regular expression for "No quotes in a string"?

Tags: asp.net, regex

I am trying to write a regular expression that doesn't allow single or double quotes in a string (could be single line or multiline string). Based on my last question, I wrote like this `^(?:(?!"|').)*$`, but it is not working. Really appreciate if anybody could help me out here.

Comment: the `.Contains` method is not an solution for this case?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just use a character class that excludes quotes:

```
^[^'"]*$
```

(Within the `[]` character class specifier, the `^` prefix inverts the specification, so `[^'"]` means any character that isn't a `'` or `"`.)

Comment: Not all cases allow direct manipulation of match results - for instance, libraries may often allow the specification of a validation regex, but the logic that actually uses the regex isn't exposed.

Comment: Sorry I tried, it didn't work. And regular string cannot pass it.

Comment: @GaolaiPeng - Then post the code you're using to evaluate it; the regex should work fine.

Comment: @Amber: Hmm, okay, I hadn't thought of that. I read the question as a homebrew solution. (Note to self: If I write a validation library that takes a regex, I must specify a negation option...)

Comment: I tried, good, "good", 'good', none passed. I put following in my aspx, ValidationExpression="^[^'"]*$".

Comment: @GaolaiPeng You need to escape the double quote, since your argument is quoted using double quotes: `ValidationExpression="^[^'\"]*$"`

Comment: I tried ValidationExpression="^[^'|&quot;]*$", it worked. Thanks everyone!

Comment: It doesn't work with `"./router.js"`, the result of that is `router` rather than `./router.js`

Answer (score 0):

Just use a regex that matches for quotes, and then negate the match result:

```
var regex = new Regex("\"|'");
bool noQuotes = !regex.IsMatch("My string without quotes");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't want to write it in code-behind.

Comment: You never said this was in a view. :-( Maybe you should have it in a model object?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    string myStr = "foo'baa";
    bool HasQuotes = myStr.Contains("'") || myStr.Contains("\""); //faster solution , I think.
    bool HasQuotes2 = Regex.IsMatch(myStr, "['\"]");

                if (!HasQuotes)
                {
                    //not has quotes.. 
                }
```

Answer (score -1):

This regular expression below, allows alphanumeric and all special characters except quotes(' and  "")

```
@"^[a-zA-Z-0-9~+:;,/#&_@*%$!()\[\] ]*$"
```

You can use it like

```
[RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z-0-9~+:;,/#&_@*%$!()**\[\]** ]*$", ErrorMessage = "Should not allow quotes")]
```

here use escape sequence() for []. Since its not showing in this post